# c++ char comparison to see if a string is fits our needs

Tags: c++, string, comparison, char

i want to do my work if chars of the string variable `tablolar` does not contain any char but small letters between `a-z` and `','`. what do you suggest?

if string tablolar is;

"tablo"->it is ok

"tablo,tablobir,tabloiki,tablouc"->it is ok

"ta"->it is ok

but if it is;

"tablo2"->not ok

"ta546465"->not ok

"Tablo"->not ok

"tablo,234,tablobir"->not ok

"tablo^%&!)=(,tablouc"-> not ok

what i tried was wrog;

```
    for(int z=0;z<tablolar.size();z++){
    if ((tablolar[z] == ',') || (tablolar[z] >= 'a' && tablolar[z] <= 'z'))
{//do your work here}}
```

Comment: The error in your code is that you do work for every valid character in the string.  Instead, you should first check all characters and then only do work when they are all valid.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it "[did] your work" once for every character that matched, instead of recording whether the entire string matched or not then deciding whether to do the work (once)....  You can move it into a function as per Detheroc's answer or just set a boolean to false when you find an illegal character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tablolar.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijknmopqrstuvwxyz,")` will return the position of the first invalid character, or `std::string::npos` if the string is OK.

Comment: This is a good key to the solution. Might I suggest expanding with some more explanation of how he should use it?

Comment: @hmz: `bool good = tablolar.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijknmopqrstuvwxyz,") == std::string::npos`

Answer (score 0):

```
bool fitsOurNeeds(const std::string &tablolar) {
    for (int z=0; z < tablolar.size(); z++)
        if (!((tablolar[z] == ',') || (tablolar[z] >= 'a' && tablolar[z] <= 'z')))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why `int`? What if `'a'` through `'z'` are not assigned consecutive codes as `'0'` through `'9'`?

Comment: What's wrong with int? Is that a common thing that they don't have consecutive codes?

Comment: @Detheroc: Yes, on IBM systems. (EBCDIC).

Comment: @MSalters: so the question might be, are IBM systems common ? :D

Comment: `int` is likely unable to receive all values that `string::size()` can return. And then, it may give you a warning, if you use warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The c function **islower** tests for lowercase. So you probably want something along these lines:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype> // for islower

bool fitsOurNeeds(std::string const& tabular)
{
    return std::all_of(tabular.begin(), tabular.end(),
        [](char ch)
    {
        return islower(ch) || ch == ',';
    });
}
```